# Having trouble POSTing nested JSON using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to send some form data as a JSON object to a [sample app on Force.com](https://cmsamp.secure.force.com/GenericApp/services/apexrest/GenericApp). I get the form data using jQuery and POST it to a PHP file on my server which then sends it to the sample app linked above. The response I get from the sample app however tells me that I'm making some mistakes along the way.

**The PHP file that talks to the sample Force.com app:**

```
<?php

    $url = 'https://cmsamp.secure.force.com/GenericApp/services/apexrest/GenericApp';
    $data = $_POST[ 'data'];

    $options = array('http' => array('method'  => 'POST','content' => http_build_query($data)));
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    echo $result;

?>
```

**Client-side jQuery code that posts form data to the PHP file:**

```
var sample_form_data = {"attributes":{"type":"Generic_App__c"},"Application_Type__c":"iPay","Return_Email__c":"lsmith@cmsrep.com","Name":"Bus Test","ACHRejectFee__c":"123456789","ApplicationDate__c":"2000-01-01","BusinessPhone__c":"(555) 123-4567","Email__c":"thetest@testemail.com","InternetPercentage2__c":"0","MailingState__c":"CA","MOTO7__c":"true","NumOfLocations__c":"15"};

$.post( url, { data: JSON.stringify( sample_form_data ) }, function( result ) { 
    console.log( result );
});
```

**The response from I get from the Force.com app:**

```
"No content to map to Object due to end of inputInsert failed. 
First exception on row 0; 
first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, 
Required fields are missing: [Name]: [Name]"
```

**Desired "success" response:**

```
"Success: 
Generic App Object: Bus Test; was successfully created and inserted"
```

This is the output of `var_dump($data)` in the php code (line breaks added for readability:

```
string(405)
    "{\"attributes\":
        {\"type\":\"Generic_App__c\"},
    \"Application_Type__c\":\"iPay\",
    \"‌​Return_Email__c\":\"lsmith@cmsrep.com\",
    \"Name\":\"Bus Test\",
    \"ACHRejectFee__c\":\"123456789\",
    \"ApplicationDate__c\":\"2000-01-01\",
    \"B‌​usinessPhone__c\":\"(555) 123-4567\",
    \"Email__c\":\"thetest@testemail.com\",
    \"InternetPercentage2__c\":\"0\"‌​,
    \"MailingState__c\":\"CA\",
    \"MOTO7__c\":\"true\",
    \"NumOfLocations__c\":\"15\"
    }"
```

The generic app just expects to get a JSON object with the proper fields. When I submit the following through a REST client it works as intended (again, line breaks added for readability):

```
{"attributes":
    {"type":"Generic_App__c"},
"Application_Type__c":"iPay",
"Return_Email‌​__c":"test@example.org",
"Name":"Bus Test",
"ACHRejectFee__c":"123456789",
"ApplicationDate__c":"2000-01-01",
"BusinessPho‌​ne__c":"(555) 123-4567",
"Email__c":"thetest@testemail.com",
"InternetPercentage2__c":"0",
"Mailing‌​State__c":"CA",
"MOTO7__c":"true",
"NumOfLocations__c":"15"}
```

Anyone have ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: var_dump your json object that you're sending over

Comment: Agreed, the output of this (from your php file) would be very helpful `var_dump($data);`. Also, is there documentation on what the sample app is expecting? The response messages from the actual handler aren't enough to tell what format it is expecting.

Comment: @NathanMann - This is the output - string(405) "{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Generic_App__c\"},\"Application_Type__c\":\"iPay\",\"Return_Email__c\":\"lsmith@cmsrep.com\",\"Name\":\"Bus Test\",\"ACHRejectFee__c\":\"123456789\",\"ApplicationDate__c\":\"2000-01-01\",\"BusinessPhone__c\":\"(555) 123-4567\",\"Email__c\":\"thetest@testemail.com\",\"InternetPercentage2__c\":\"0\",\"MailingState__c\":\"CA\",\"MOTO7__c\":\"true\",\"NumOfLocations__c\":\"15\"}"

Comment: @PatrickM - It just expects to get a JSON object with the proper fields. When I submit the following through a REST client it works as intended - {"attributes":{"type":"Generic_App__c"},"Application_Type__c":"iPay","Return_Email__c":"test@example.org","Name":"Bus Test","ACHRejectFee__c":"123456789","ApplicationDate__c":"2000-01-01","BusinessPhone__c":"(555) 123-4567","Email__c":"thetest@testemail.com","InternetPercentage2__c":"0","MailingState__c":"CA","MOTO7__c":"true","NumOfLocations__c":"15"}

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of those var_dumps, I'd say you need to strip those slashes out of $data before you use it. Try [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

Comment: I think var_dump might add those on its own because the source string has quotes in it. stripslashes is worth a shot though.

Comment: added stripslashes - same error - var_dump now says - string(355) "{"attributes":{"type":"Generic_App__c"},"Application_Type__c":"iPay","Return_Email__c":"lsmith@cmsrep.com","Name":"Bus Test","ACHRejectFee__c":"123456789","ApplicationDate__c":"2000-01-01","BusinessPhone__c":"(555) 123-4567","Email__c":"thetest@testemail.com","InternetPercentage2__c":"0","MailingState__c":"CA","MOTO7__c":"true","NumOfLocations__c":"15"}"

Comment: Well, the good news is, that's almost certainly a step in the right direction. Bad news, as you know, is that it's not the entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

[http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) also expects an array. Since your data is already a json string, I think you should probably omit it. You may need to url encode it, but you should just use the regular [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function for that.

Also, I'm not familiar with the php context mechanism you're using and I'm deeply unsatisfied with the php.net documentation, but I can't shake this nagging feeling that the `'content' => $data` is doing something more than just setting the content. Do you have a good documentation link for the stream contexts actually using the `'content'` option?

Comment: I tried this after trying stripslashes - Same error - maybe I didn't understand what exactly I was supposed to replace. Changed `$options = array('http' => array('method'  => 'POST','content' => http_build_query($data)));` to `$options = array('http' => array('method'  => 'POST','content' => urlencode($data)));`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you're asking in the second part of your post. I'm very much a beginner here.

Comment: I guess I'm asking where or how you learned to use `file_get_contents` with the `stream_context_create` thing. I'm a beginner with that, too, so you're in good company.

Comment: It's a code sample I found on StackOverflow somewhere. Essentially all I'm trying to accomplish is to take a html form, package it into json with jquery and post to a url using php. It's been awhile since I've worked with php so I looked for a starting point for the php script. If there's a better way to write the php, I'm open to it. Thanks!